# How to open the file if path is known?

Tags: c#, listbox

I am having path in `listbox`.I want to open the file on `listbox` item click.

I am using `SelectedIndexChanged`,From that I am able to know item which is clicked. Now, I want to open that.

Comment: What's the exact problem?

Comment: Open where? In your application?

Comment: Do you want to read it and put in some textblock/richtextbox or what you want to do? Be more specific.

Comment: what is the format of file?

Comment: What kind of file? Is it an executable that you want to run, or maybe a textfile? Or do you want to know how to read the path from your listbox's selected item?

Comment: Hey, if you have difficulties to describe the question, try posting the code.

Comment: Please also include information on whether or not the source for the listbox is trustworthy. Although it's not that difficult to write an `if` with `System.IO.File.Exists` after you get the file name.

Answer (score 2):

```
public  void OpenDialogBox()
{
    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "*YOURTEXTBOX.text";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
               //Do something with Open File
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // You messed up
        }
    }
}
```